# Remove duplicate Google Chrome app

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

There was a time that my mother and my sister share a common PC (Windows 7), and by that they also share uses the same browser, Google Chrome. They both have different Google Chrome accounts on that browser. Each account has it's own list of Google Apps. They have unique apps on each account, though they also have some common app (e.g. Hangouts, some offline games, etc.)

When my sister bought her own laptop, my mother remove her account on Google Chrome. But it seems my sister's app is not removed on the process. We tried using registry cleaning software (CCleaner, etc.) but it is not removed. She reinstalled the browser, but the same apps still persists. How can we remove the duplicate apps.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "remove a person" from Chrome, all their Chrome data will be erased from the device.It looks like your mother removed your sister's account in a wrong way.Ways to remove the account correctly:

### A. Easy way

(from 
[Installing Chrome for another user - Google Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/-ecrbGrqlNE))

> 1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the button for the current user. (It might show a name or email address.)
> 2. Select Switch person.
> 3. Mouse over the person you want to remove.
> 4. In the top-right corner of the person’s card, click the downward arrow.
> 5. Click Remove This Person.
> 6. In the confirmation dialog that appears, click Remove This Person.

### B. Another easy way

1. Click on the wrench icon.
2. Settings.
3. Scroll down till you find People category.
4. Under people  select the profile you want to remove.
5. Click Remove.
6. Confirm Remove.

Comment: Hi, the account has been removed via **Settings** > **People** > **Remove...**. Isn't that also a correct way?

Comment: Yes of course, that should also do the thing you want.Still having two hangouts ?

Comment: When copying content from external sources *at a minimum* you should provide proper attribution and link to the source. You should also put the quoted text in a blockquote.